# Does Tosk kill the hunters when he shoots them?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the DS9 episode "Captive Pursuit" Tosk shoots the hunters:

> O'BRIEN: Come on, Tosk. Round this corner and we're there.  (Hunter
>   and two aliens beam in.)
>
> HUNTER: No. He is mine.  (Hunter fires. Tosk pushes O'Brien aside and
>   dodges the fire)
>
> O'BRIEN: No.  (Tosk shoots Hunter and his companions)
>
> O'BRIEN: Go on.

Does Tosk kill the Hunters or just stun them? Do we learn more about how the whole hunter/hunted relationship and rules are to know the answer to this?

It seems like in every other instance Tosk only stuns or knocks out the hunters. It'd be a better self preservation strategy to kill them so they can no longer pursue them and bring the hunters numbers down as well, if it's allowed in the rules of the hunt.

Comment: Given that my answer specifically references the show's script, I felt that it was quite comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd like addressed before offering an acceptance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [show script](http://ds9.trekcore.com/media/scripts/106.txt) indicates that the two helmeted hunters were left "dazed" and that the "lead hunter" was killed by the crossbow blast:

> **104  SLOW MOTION - ANGLE PAST TOSK AND O'BRIEN (OPTICAL)**
>   as the charge zips between them and explodes against the back door...
>
> **105  SLOW MOTION - TOSK (OPTICAL)**
>   rolls over, cocks and aims the crossbow in one fluid motion and fires...
>
> **106  SLOW MOTION - THE HUNTER (OPTICAL)**
>   by reflex, he raises his arm to try his shields but they  aren't strong enough to repel his
>   own weapon... he catches  it full force and disappears in the white
>   fire... the fading  shock the last thing we see on his face... the
>   other aliens  are thrown to the side... and we END SLOW MOTION as...
>
> **107  O'BRIEN AND TOSK**
>   run through them easily now... **O'Brien glancing with distaste at the remains of the Hunter... [and] the dazed
>   aliens on the  floor...**

[image]

As to the 'rules' of the Hunt, it's worth noting that this isn't the first hunter he's killed. He also forced the 2nd hunter off of the balcony where he was likely killed by the fall.